# Как использовать подпись разработчика?

Tags: android

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно подписать приложение подписью разработчика? Просто мне нужно заменить один файл в **APK**. А после замены, оно не устанавливается, приходиться подписывать тестовой подписью, но тогда в приложении не работают Google-покупки и прочее.

Comment: Попросите ключ у разработчика, а то тогда Вы не сможете залить новую версию с новыми файлами. P.S. Ключ не достать, иначе бы было много проблем.

Comment: Подпись РАЗРАБОТЧИКА на то и подпись разработчика, чтобы другие Александры не могли заменить ни один файл в чужой программе

Answer (score 0):

Как мне известно, вам нужно подписать полученный APK через команду:

```
apksigner sign --ks apk-release-key.jks --out app-release.apk app-unsigned-aligned.apk
```

Где:

`apk-release-key.jks` - ваш ключ, который нужен для подписи

`app-unsigned-aligned.apk` - ваше приложение неподписанное

`app-release.apk` - на выходе получите подписанный апк

Comment: А как можно достать ключ из приложения, подписанного разработчиком?

Comment: Если често не знаю если такая возможность. Читайте Документацию